# Distribution of the distance from the closest larger neighbour

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose I have N points placed at random positions $x_{i}, i = 1, \dots, N$, where $x_{i}$'s are iid random variables uniformly distributed in the interval $[0,1]$. I assign to each of these points a random number, called $h_{i}$, picked from a distribution $p_{h}(h)$. We can think of these points as trees in positions $x_{i}$, each with random height $h_{i}$. Let's call $r_{i}$ the distance from tree $i$ to the nearest higher tree. The question is: is it possible to analytically determine the distribution of the $r_{i}$'s, $p_{r}(r)$? Can this be extended also in 2 dimensions? I have tried with a simulation in 2 dimensions and it seems that the distribution should be proportional to $r^{-3}$. However I was not able to proceed analytically.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Let's set $X_{(a)}<X_{(a+1)}$ the two neighbour ordered rv's.

Using [Order statistics](http://www.math.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ehchen/teaching/LargeSample/notes/noteorder.pdf) (look at "General Properties" (3) on page 4) you can find that

$$f_{X_{(a)}X_{(a+1)}}(x,y)=\frac{n!}{(a-1)!(n-a-1)!}x^{a-1}(1-y)^{n-a-1}\times \mathbb{1}_{[0;1]}(x)\times \mathbb{1}_{[x;1]}(y)$$

Now you can find the density of the distance $Z=X_{(a+1)}-X_{(a)}$ simply integrating over the purple area

[image]

That is easier to calculate 1 minus the integral over the upper white triangle...

$$f_Z(z)=1-\int_{0}^{1-z}\Bigg[\int_{x+z}^{1}f(x,y)dy\Bigg]dx$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But from what I've understood I think that this gives the distribution of the difference between tree heights, whereas I'm looking for the spatial distance from the nearest higher tree. I've edited the question to (hopefully) make it more clear.